# $f(f(f(x)))=x$, does it necessarily imply $f(x)=x$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> **[TIFR GS-2017]** Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying the relation
> $$f(f(f(x))) = x\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$$ Prove or disprove that $f$ is the identity function.

There is a solution to this question [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258564/fffx-x-prove-or-disprove-that-f-is-the-identity-function), but I was trying in this way...

Suppose $f$ is continuous and not identity function. Then we can find some point $c \in \mathbb R$ such that there is a neighbourhood $N_\delta(c)$, where $f(x) \neq x\ \forall x \in \mathbb N_\delta(c)$.

Then two cases arise.

$\underline{Case (i)}:$ $f(f(x))=f(x)$, but that means $f(f(x))=f(x)\neq x$, hence $f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x)) =f(x) \neq x$.

Hence we have a contradiction.

$\underline{Case (ii)}:$ $f(f(x)) \neq f(x)$.

Suppose $p$ be such a point where it holds. Then $f(f(p)) \neq f(p)$. Suppose $m \in \mathbb R$ s.t. it is in between $f(f(p))$ and $f(p)$. Then by IMVP, there is some $q$ between $p$ and $f(p)$ s.t. $f(q) = m$.

After this scene, I am out of ideas to proceed further. We can't say that $f(p) \in N_\delta(c)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just for others reading this post, the condition of continuity on $f(x)$ is extremely important to this question. If this condition is not included, then $f(x)$ need not be the identity. In fact, going down the rabbit hole of linked questions, the accepted answer at the [bottom](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195861/364346) gives the example

$$f(x)=\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3}+1}$$

which satisfies $f(f(f(x)))=x$. However, this obviously is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and as such is not a counterexample to the question presented in OP's post. To answer this question, consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Since both $f(x)$ and $x$ are continuous, this function is a continuous function. We will show that it is identically zero. First, note that there must be $x_0$ such that $g(x)=0$. If this were not the case, then either $f(x)>x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In the first case, this would then imply

$$x=f(f(f(x)))$$

$$\Rightarrow f(f(x))<x$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x)<x$$

$$\Rightarrow x<x$$

which is obviously a contradiction. The case where $f(x)<x$ follows in the same manner. Now, the places where $g(x)>0$ form a countable sequence of open intervals. There are four possibilities for the open interval with $x_0$ as an endpoint:

$$(x_0,\infty)$$

$$(x_0,b)$$

$$(-\infty,x_0)$$

$$(a,x_0)$$

(where $a<x_0<b$) and it is possible that multiple of these apply. In addition, there are the possibilities  that $g(x)=0$ for $x\in [a,b]$ where $a<x_0<b$, $g(x)=0$ for $x\in [a,\infty)$ where $a<x_0$, $g(x)=0$ for $x\in (-\infty,b]$ where $x_0<b$, or $g(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, as the argument for these seven cases (as the eight case is what we are trying to prove) are basically identical, we will only prove the first possibility. Thus, consider the interval $(x_0,\infty)$. In this interval, $g(x)>0$ or $g(x)<0$. In the first case, let $\epsilon_n>0$ be any sequence that approaches $0$. Then eventually

$$x_0+\epsilon_n=f(f(f(x_0+\epsilon_n)))>f(f(x_0+\epsilon_n)>f(x_0+\epsilon_n)>x_0+\epsilon_n$$

As this is a contradiction, we conclude that this open interval cannot actually exist and therefore $g(x)=0$ for $x\in (x_0,\infty)$. This argument can be expanded to the other four cases above, and from there expanded by induction to the entire real number line. We conclude that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: For the first example, $f$ is not defined on all of $\Bbb R$, and so you need to add its definition at $-1/\surd3$, namely $f(-1/\surd3):=-1/\surd3$.

Comment: Would be clearer by taking $a$ where $g(a)=0$ and investigating the sign on $(a,a+\epsilon)$ and $(a-\epsilon,a)$ to obtain that $g^{-1}(0)$ is a non-empty closed subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with no boundary point.

Comment: @JohnBentin Yes, that was the point. I was noting how that example does not work for this case

Comment: Your point was (quite correctly) that the function failed to be a counterexample because it was discontinuous, not that it failed because it was undefined at some point.

Comment: A simpler non-continuous example is $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: Yes, that answer is vastly helpful, but it is a direct proof. I was wondering whether we could arrive at a contradiction on the fact that $f(f(f(x)))=x$ using my way :(

Answer (score 1):

**Continuity is important**

As the others pointed out, the requirement that the function *f* is *continuous* is very important here.

If we formally answer not the question in your text, *"Let f be a continuous function ..."*, but the question in the title, where continuity is not mentioned, then **many** solutions are possible.

Here is an example. Unlike other examples, where function is undefined in some points, following function is defined **for every value of x:**
$$f(x) = floor(x) + frac(frac(x) + 1/3)$$
[image: f(x) = floor(x) + frac(frac(x) + 1/3)]

For any *x* following holds:
$$f(f(f(x))) = x$$

But this function is *not continuous* and thus does not prove anything.

**Proof of not existence**

You wanted to have a proof based on contradiction. It is possible, but not exactly the way you started. First I'd suggest to show that if *f(x)* exists, then it must be *monotone*. Then you can consider separate cases how *f(x)* can be located relative to *y(x) = x*. There are only a few types possible. If you look at each case closer, you will come to contradiction.

Comment: I appreciate it, but may I ask why the process in which I have started can't be finished? Is there any problem in my logic and my process?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick: Because it does not lead to contradiction. You take one point, another point, between these points there are millions of other points. So what? There is no reason for contradiction. But if you you consider what I suggested, you can come to contradictions.

Comment: thanks man! That's what I wanted to know.