# Find monotone functions $f:\Bbb{R}^*\to\Bbb{R}^*$ such that $f\left (\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)}\right)=x,\forall x\in\Bbb R^*$

Tags: functions

Find all monotone functions $f: \mathbb{R^{*}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{*}}$ with this propriety
$$f\left ( \frac{1}{f\left ( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right )} \right )=x,\forall x\in \mathbb R^{*}$$

Any help would be appreciated. I don't really know how to start this problem, I haven't found anything similar with it.(it's a 9th grade problem)

Comment: have u tried f(x)=x ?

Comment: One way to start this problem is to try different forms of $ax^b$, $a^x$, $\log x$, and then seeing how the end up, it might get close to $x$ and you can adjust it from there. Obviously if you have for instance: $f(f(f(x)))=x$, the solution will never be $a^x$ since you'll just get $a^{a^{a^{x}}}$, and you can look to the next attempt. For this example, I would personally start with $f(x)=\frac1x$ and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try

Comment: For simplicity, you want to let $g(x)=f(1/x)$. This boils down to a problem analogous to [f(f(x)) = 1/x](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h598477p3551541).

Comment: Thank you for the idea!

Comment: As a matter of fact, by working out the above further by applying the entire resulting equation to itself in the same manner as shown in the link, one gets [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3305915/272831).