# Functions that satisfy $f(f(f(x))) = x$ for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

This is my first post on Math SE soo... I was reading over [a thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758951/suppose-a-function-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-satisfies-fffx) a while ago that claims the only solution to $f(f(f(x))) = x$ for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $f(x) = x$, but.. I seemed to have found a counterexample:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Here, we have
$$f(f(f(x))) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-x}{x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = x$$
Well... looking over the original problem statement, would we say that my function satisfies $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Or would it be something more like $f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: yes i think the domain $\text{dom} (f)$ is the issue

Comment: Your proposed function does not work since, as noted, its domain is not $\Bbb R$ but $\Bbb R \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: got it! :3 thanks.

Comment: It also doesn’t work because it’s not strictly increasing - $f(0) > f(2)$, for example. The problem stated that if $f$ is strictly increasing, then $f$ is the identity function.

Comment: What is $f(1)?$

Comment: Yeah, I see where my point breaks down now. $f(1)$ is undefined which doesn't satisfy the original problem proposed. (it's also not strictly increasing as Mark Saving pointed out) Thanks guys!

Comment: And what is $f(f(0))?$

Comment: yeah, that's also undefined.

Comment: If $f$ is assumed to be continuous, then one can prove that $f$ is identity. Otherwise the question makes no sense as one can choose any partition of $\Bbb R$ into subsets of three elements and define an arbitrary function.

Comment: if I have a follow-up question that I'd like to ask would I make another post for it? or would I ask in the comments section?

Comment: But there are a lot of functions of this form (Möbius transformations) $X\to X,$ where $X$ is $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ or $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}.$ If $a+d=-1, ad-bc=1,$ then $$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ satisfies this condition. These are continuous on these “projective lines.” $a=0,b=-1,c=1,d=-1$ gives tour case.

Comment: An example of a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $f(f(f(x))) = x$ is
$$ f(x) = \cases{x - 2 & if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is divisible by $3$\cr x+1 & otherwise}$$

Comment: that's an interesting example... thanks for the notes guys!